# Change Confirm options in botframework Formflow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I have created a formflow in botframework. I want to change the confirmation options, by default it takes 'Yes' and 'No'. but i want it to proceed instead 'Yes', even if user inputs 'OK', 'Ya', 'Yeah' etc. how i can add options for confirmation

Comment: I know there are some ways to alter the way the form asks questions. this is done with annotations. But I haven't tried it yet with confirmations.
Here is the documentation : https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dd/df7/namespace_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow.html#a28ef6a551a3611e4a6abe06659797313

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the new terms to the `Yes` array of the FormBuilder configuration. Something like:

```
public static IFormBuilder<T> CreateCustomForm<T>()
    where T : class
{
    var form = new FormBuilder<T>();
    var yesTerms = form.Configuration.Yes.ToList();
    yesTerms.Add("Ya");
    form.Configuration.Yes = yesTerms.ToArray();

    return form;
}
```

That then you can use like:

```
 return CreateCustomForm<MyForm>()
```

The reason of this would be something like the following:

The [Confirmation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Confirmation.cs) field, set it's [type to bool](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Confirmation.cs#L59). At some point, a [recognizer is defined for the field](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Field.cs#L701), based on it's type. In this, case, the `Confirmation` field will use the [RecognizeBool](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Recognize.cs#L460) recognizer.

The recognizer uses the [Yes/No](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Recognize.cs#L470-L473) arrays defined in the form's configuration (which initially they [are retrieved](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/IFormBuilder.cs#L301) from the [resource file](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Resource/Resources.en.resx#L92)) for doing [the parsing](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Recognize.cs#L476).

When the `Confirmation` field is added to the Form, [a ConfirmStep step is also added](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/FormBuilder.cs#L153). The [ConfirmStep](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Steps.cs#L526) is the one that later in the game [ends up calling the recognizer](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Steps.cs#L564) to do the matching and parsing of the terms.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. I will try this code