# Set Formconfiguration in FormBuilder fails due to accessibility

Tags: c#, botframework, formbuilder

I installed the Nuget packages of the Botbuilder. I've succesfully created a bot with Luis and the bot SDK. However, I am trying to set some configuration for a form made by the formbuilder.

This property only contains a get; and therefore is unable to be set. However, in almost all examples I see people setting values (such as changing default text).

```
var noChangeString = new string[] { "Test"};
var builder = new FormBuilder<Website>()
                    .Message("Welcome to the builder!")
                    .Field(nameof(Id), active: (state) => false)
                    .AddRemainingFields()
                    .Build();

builder.Configuration.Templates.Single(t => t.Usage == TemplateUsage.NoPreference).Patterns = noPreferenceStrings;
```

The configuration line tells me : .Configuration is inaccessible due ot its protection level.
I cannot add a setter into the property because it's installed via NuGet.

How to set some configuration on these formbuilder without adding a setter in source code?

Comment: `in almost all examples I see people setting values` Could you share the links to examples that you seen before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947804/change-confirm-options-in-botframework-formflow https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1420 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060923/how-to-change-the-default-button-label-no-preference-in-formflow